# Transposing one column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following:

```
Index  ID     speed  _avg_val
245    1      10      30.5
246    1      2       25.1
```

I want to transpose the column ID and then have the following:

```
ID (Index)    speed   _avg_val   speed_y   _avg_val_y
1             10      30.5       2         25.1
```

I tried to use this method [Transposing one column in python pandas with the simplest index possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942167/transposing-one-column-in-python-pandas-with-the-simplest-index-possible) but could not get this to work with multiple columns.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What happens if you have more rows?

Comment: `Index` with values `245` and `246` is not necessary?

Comment: I am trying to group the duplicate ID and then have its variable be transposed into a single row. So if you more rows it would simply add more columns to the right. 

Currently I have 1000+ columns, so in this case my df.shape is the following: (1118,18). Once transposed it should have a df.shape of (~700,~200).

Comment: @jezrael Index with 245 and 246 is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first remove column `Index`, then add column `ID` to `index`, [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and sort second level of MultiIndex in columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print (df)
   Index  ID  speed  _avg_val
0    245   1     10      30.5
1    246   1      2      25.1


df = df.drop('Index', axis=1)
       .set_index('ID', append=True)
       .unstack(0)
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)

#remove MultiIndex from columns
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df.columns]

print (df)
    speed_0  _avg_val_0  speed_1  _avg_val_1
ID                                          
1        10        30.5        2        25.1
```

If there is more values in `ID` column, need use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df)
   Index  ID  speed  _avg_val
0    245   1     10      30.5
1    246   1      2      25.1
2    245   2      5      37.5
3    246   2     28      28.1
4    246   2     27      23.0

df = df.drop('Index', axis=1)
df['g'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'g']).unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df.columns]

print (df)
    speed_0  _avg_val_0  speed_1  _avg_val_1  speed_2  _avg_val_2
ID                                                               
1        10        30.5        2        25.1        0         0.0
2         5        37.5       28        28.1       27        23.0
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for! 
How can I keep the order so that the output is 
   speed_0 _avg_val_0 speed_1 _avg_val_1?

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to get this to work with ID containing multiple values?